# Incorrect string value: '\xE8.. &n...' for column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, utf-8

I'm creating a ticket system in PHP which uses imap to fetch mail from an Exchange server.

When I'm putting the HTML message from the email in a MySQL database, the following error occurs when there is a special char in the message body like è:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xE8. ' for column 'message' at row 1
```

I allready tried stuff like:

```
utf8_encode($message);
```

But that just removes all the HTML from the message which shouldn't happen.

The MySQL table:

```
mysql> show create table crm.tickets;
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table   | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| tickets | CREATE TABLE `tickets` (
  `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `senderName` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `senderEmail` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `companyID` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userID` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` longtext,
  `timestamp` int(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `toName` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `toEmail` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ownerID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticketStatus` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ticketType` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeSpend` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `locked` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `queue` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: What character set is the MySQL table using? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset.html

Comment: @HenryTK See my post, did an edit.

Comment: What is the character set of the connection to mysql server? Do you execute `SET NAMES 'utf8'` as the first statement?

Comment: @Marek Seems that I get the same error with SET NAMES

Comment: è is a valid UTF-8 character. Here's a useful reference for escaping:  http://www.charbase.com/00e8-unicode-latin-small-letter-e-with-grave

Comment: @HenryTK Yeah but since It's Microsoft the sign is something like =E8. and I can only replace that in the original message body, but then I have too much info. Still trying to figure this one out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an own function to replace all the Microsoft chars to HTML chars.
Working like a charm!